# LaTeX configuration issue on Mac - unable to typeset

Tags: latex, pdflatex, miktex, tex-live

I am trying to install and use LaTeX on my Mac. I have used it on Windows before without issue, but after installing MacTex when I try to typeset a document in pdflatex it comes up with an error, even though nothing has changed in the code from when I created it in Windows.

On my Windows PC I used TeXworks to edit, and MikTeX was installed. I feel like the issue must be that I don't have a particular package installed on my Mac but I don't know what it is. I tried to install MikTeX on the Mac but I can't download it, and I've been lead to believe that the MacTeX package should provide the same functionality.

This is the start of the code, and the point at which it appears to get stuck:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry, graphicx,float,appendix, times}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 inner=30mm,
 top=20mm,
 outer=25mm,
 bottom=40mm,
 }
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
...
```

This is the output that shows when I attempt to typeset[1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQuHB.png

I'm afraid I'm really a novice with this sort of thing so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be an error in the .aux file. Can you throw away all auxiliary files and compile again? If this does not help, please make a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to have done the trick!

Comment: BTW, please include such error messages as text instead of an image. That increases the chance that other people with the same problem can find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you show indicates that there is some error in the `.aux` file. This can for example happen if the previous compilation did not finish successfully or if one switches between tex distributions that might have different versions of latex and/or the packages.

#### Fix:

Delete all the auxiliary files and compile again